# Meteor access tokens

Tags: oauth, meteor

When using [Meteor](http://meteor.com), with the new [authentication](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/auth) system, how can I get facebook **access token**, when logged with `accounts-facebook` package?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

get it either from a Meteor.method:

```
// server
Meteor.methods({
  getAccessToken : function() {
    try {
      return Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken;
    } catch(e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}); 

// client
Meteor.call("getAccessToken", function(error, accessToken){
   console.log(accessToken);
})
```

or publish it:

```
//server
Meteor.publish("currentUserAccessToken", function(){
    var self = this;
    if (this.userId()){
        handle = Meteor.users.find(this.userId()).observe({
            added: function(user){
                self.set("currentUserAccessToken", user._id, {value: user.services.facebook.accessToken});
                self.flush();
            },
            changed: function(user){
                self.set("currentUserAccessToken", user._id, {value: user.services.facebook.accessToken});
                self.flush();
            }
        });

        this.onStop(function() {
            handle.stop();
        });
    }
});

//client
var AccessToken = new Meteor.Collection("currentUserAccessToken");
Meteor.subscribe("currentUserAccessToken");

//access the value
var accessToken = AccessToken.findOne().value;
```

Comment: you saved the day (actually, few days). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Updating and simplifying [Lloyd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12656991/599991), we get this:

## server

```
Meteor.publish("currentAccessToken", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {'services.facebook.accessToken': 1}});
});
```

## client

```
Meteor.autosubscribe(function(){
  var newUser = Meteor.user();
  Meteor.subscribe('currentAccessToken');
});
```

It updates every time your user changes status, and access token can be accessed (when exists) by `Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken`