# How to get user access token in Meteor.JS after logging in by facebook

Tags: facebook, meteor, publish, subscribe

After I'm logged in using facebook account I have access to `Meteor.userId()`

So I tried to publish user data this way from the server:

```
Meteor.publish('getUserAccessToken', function(userId) {
  return Meteor.users.find(userId).fetch();
});
```

And receive it on client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("getUserAccessToken",Meteor.userId());
```

then I would like to dig through returned user object  to it's accessToken

```
console.log([Object].services.facebook.accessToken);
```

but since I remove autopublish `services.facebook` disappear for client.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor.access tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570793/meteor-access-tokens)

Comment: Thanks! So the solution was to publish accessToken using Meteor Method instead of Publishing, and receive it using Meteor Call instead of Subscribe. Done, and working :)